# Showing multiple table rows in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am somewhat new to PHP and am running into an issue.  Here is what I have:

```
$select_all = "SELECT * FROM latesttest";

$result = mysql_query($select_all)
    or die(mysql_error());


$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

foreach($row as $k=>$v){
    echo $k . "=" . $v . "<br />";
}
```

This works and gives me:
     V1=Test
     V2=1234
     V3=Something
etc.

But I want to have the results for each row in the table reflected in this way. If I run the SELECT * FROM latesttest; in MySQL, I have 4 records in this table.  How do I show all 4 rows in this above format?

Comment: Just to note that learning mysql with the mysql_ functions is a bad idea. These functions are old, php now has a new version, you should use the mysqli_ family of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  foreach($row as $k=>$v){
      echo $k . "=" . $v . "<br />";
  }
}
```

Ta-da!

Answer (score 5):

fetch_assoc() only returns a SINGLE result row as an array, so your for() loop is just iterating over the fields in that one row. The code should be

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
        echo "$key => $val<br />";
    }
}
```